# How to create one static div and one reponsive div along side each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the left column static and the contentwrapper responsive to browser resizing. I do not want to use floats because when I do not want it to shift the content down.

HTML

```
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
    </div>

    <div id="contentwrapper">   
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I have understood from your question I think you need something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/v5FZv/1/

**CSS**

```
#maincontainer{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#leftcolumn{
    display:table-cell;
    min-width:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
#contentwrapper{
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
```